# Add terminal output at the bottom of a text file

Tags: command-line, output

I am using:

```
command > ~/Desktop/file.txt
```

My problem is that I need to execute this *command* multiple times, and each time It will give me different outputs, in this moment each time I run it It erases everything and saves the new output in the file, obviously this doesn't work for me since I need to add the new output along the current output.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of `>`:

```
command >> ~/Desktop/file.txt
```

While you were using `command > ~/Desktop/file.txt`, the file `~/Desktop/file.txt` was opened by shell for *writing* the content of STDOUT (file descriptor 1). So the file's content will get overwritten every time you run the `command`.

On the other hand, shell will open the file for *appending* if you use `>>` operator. As a result the outputs of the `command` will get appended every time you run it.

I would suggest you to go through [this manual on bash redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Comment: I was easiest than I think, best answer in a couple of minutes, thanks dude!

Comment: @Castiblanco When you can, accept and upvote it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use '>>'. 
`command >> ~/Desktop/file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you're running it in a loop, you can redirect the output of the entire loop instead.

```
for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ )); do
    somecommand
done > ~/Desktop/file.txt
```

If it's a bit more complex (e.g. other things outputting as well), you can open it on a separate file descriptor.

```
exec 3> ~/Desktop/file.txt
...
somecommand >&3
...
somecommand >&3
...
exec 3>&- # closes it
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `>>`, not `>`, like this:

```
command >> /path/to/file.txt
```